# Can I make a JFrame look like JWindow?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jwindow

Can I remove the border and the minimize and close buttons from a JFrame? I can't use a JWindow because it can't handle keyListener as I understood. (At least not easily). How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

> Can I remove the border and the minimize and close buttons from a
>   JFrame?

- [JFrame.setUndecorated(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)

> I can't use a JWindow because it can't handle keyListener as I
>   understood. (At least not easily).

- JFrame, JDialog or JWindow doesn't react to KeyListener, JComponent must be `FocusOwner` or implemented `setFocusable` for KeyListener
- don't to use KeyListener, use KeyBindings instead

> I can't use a JWindow because it can't handle keyListener as I
>   understood.

- shot to the dark,
- JTextComponents aren't editable (really don't know reason) in JWindow without visible JFrame as parent

Comment: +1. Here is the link for [Swing Key bindings tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're really trying to achieve here... but would `setUndecorated(true)` do it for you?